# How to remove (2) border lines from this table?

Tags: tables

Any clues on how to easily remove those lines? I read other articles explaining the use of 'cline' command, but couldn't get it working myself.

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\scalebox{0.85}{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|}
    \hline
    bit & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    ~   & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: By the way, you may also have look on the `bytefield` package

Comment: Why do you insert `~` in the empty cells? It's not necessary to do so, really.

Comment: That is correct. They're there as place-holders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omitting the left `|` can be obtained by using a `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}`, removing just the left `|` specifier.

The lower `\hline` has to be replaced by a column specific `cline` command, which has the argument {startcolumn-endcolum}, i.e.

`\cline{2-17}` since there are 17 columns, but only the last 16 should be underlined, omitting the first one, so start at column `2`.

All columns contain the same width and specifier, so it's quicker to say

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{p{0.35cm}|}}
```

Mico made a useful comment: The `~` aren't needed at all!

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\scalebox{0.85}{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{p{0.35cm}|}}
    \hline
    bit & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{~}   & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    \cline{2-17}%
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some automated solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{othercounter}
\newcounter{loopcounter}%

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\scalebox{0.85}{%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{p{0.35cm}|}}
    \hline
    bit & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{~}   & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
    \cline{2-17}%
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}


\newcommand{\mybitbox}[2]{%
\begin{table}
\scalebox{#1}{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{#2}{p{0.35cm}|}}
    \hline
    bit \forloop[-1]{loopcounter}{\numexpr#2-2}{\number\value{loopcounter} > -1}{& \number\value{loopcounter} } \tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \forloop[-1]{loopcounter}{\numexpr#2-2}{\number\value{loopcounter} > -1}{& } \tabularnewline
    \cline{2-\numexpr#2}%
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
}%


\forloop{othercounter}{10}{\number\value{othercounter} < 17}{%
  \mybitbox{0.85}{\number\value{othercounter}}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely, this works. I appreciate the explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` is similar to the standard `{tabular}` but adds some features. Among these features, the keys `hvlines` draws all the rules except in the empty corners, computed by the key `corners`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}.
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{17}{w{c}{0.3cm}}}[hvlines,corners=SW] % SW : south-west
    bit & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
        & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]